# Download produced file with PHPWord

Tags: php, download, phpword

I am trying to use the [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) plugin to convert some HTML into .docx

But when i download the file, I get only messed up charecters like:
 `PK########�^uK�j�#c###!#######[Content_Types].xml���N�0#E�|E�-Jܲ@#5��#*Q>5'��_�8}�=��D#AC�v#)��s�G�G��5�
"j�J6,#,#'��nQ���s~�2L�)a���m#�d|5�m#F�#K�L)�s�r    V�#8�T>Z��5.x#�C,��`

Here is my code:

```
<?php
error_reporting (E_ALL | E_STRICT);
@ini_set ('display_errors', 'on');
require_once '../../../../vendor/autoload.php';

$my_content = $_POST['html_content'];

$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
$section = $phpWord->addSection();

\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html::addHtml($section, $my_content);

header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachement;filename="teste.docx"');
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
?>
```

I already searched into the Web but got no clue how to proceed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just use the builtin functionality as follows

```
$phpWord->save('teste.docx', 'Word2007', true);
```

The last parameter will force a download of the produced file.

Answer (score 0):

add a space between `attachement;` and `filename="teste.docx"` so the header will be

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="teste.docx"');
```

and add the following header:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
```

**Update**

You can try saving the file to disk and sending from it, I also head problems like this and it solved for me:

```
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save($filePath);

header("Expires: Mon, 1 Apr 1974 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D,d M YH:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header('Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.docx");
readfile($filePath);
unlink($filePath);
```